# Inserting period/stop at end of each reference

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Using author-date style, how does one insert a period or stop at the end of every reference?  I presume you have to `\renewbibmacro` and `\setunit*{\adddot}` to a specific field?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{article} % Unix options  
\usepackage{endnotes,setspace,excludeonly,etex,ifthen,etoolbox,logreq,etoolbox,keyval,url}
\usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true,maxbibnames=4,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
   \printtext[parens]{%ADDED
     \printlist{location}%
     \iflistundef{publisher}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{publisher}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{date}%
   }\nopunct% ADDED
   \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
   \printfield{volume}% % 
   \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED   \setunit*{\addcolon}% ADDED  
   \printfield{number}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield{eid}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,shore}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: We are going to need a minimal example here: the usual approach is to have references-as-sentences.

Comment: OK, not used to quoting but hope this is correct.  I've tried mashed up my code and the bibtex-examples that the great lockstep used to answer a previous post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following redefinition.:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
   \printtext[parens]{%ADDED
     \printlist{location}%
     \iflistundef{publisher}
       {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
       {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
     \printlist{publisher}%
     \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{date}%
   }\setunit{\addspace}}
```

The command `nopunct` influences the command `\finentry` which produces a final period.

To remove all final periods use:

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```